# D3v4 responsive legend

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I’m building a cartographic responsive visualization with d3 v4 and I'm having some trouble to build a legend which fully adapts to the size of the window.

Each element of the legend is now adapted when the window is resized `.attr("width", "1em").attr("height", "1em")` as well as the size of the text describing each element `.attr("x", "1.8em")`.

But I'm having some trouble to modify the following line `.attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; })` in order to lower the space between each line when the window gets smaller.

Do you have any suggestion to solve this problem? Thanks for your help!

Small part of my code:

```
var legend = d3.select("#legendecontainer").append("svg")
    .attr("class", "legend")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(color.domain())
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; })
    ;

legend.append("rect").attr("width", "1em")
    .attr("height", "1em").style("fill", color);

legend.append("text")
    .data(legendText).attr("x", "1.8em").attr("y", ".5em")
    .attr("dy", ".35em").text(function(d) { return d; });
```

Comment: If you set up your svg properly it will automatically scale with the container size without code changes or depending on em (even pixel units will scale). Your translate is using pixel units so it's not scaling as you've set it up. Try searching for "responsive svg" in google.

Comment: Thank you for you answer Dominic. In fact I didn't want to use a direct scaling of the container in order than the size of the text decreases slowlier than the size of other elements for readability.